# Receiving 500.19 from IIS7 with a Virtual Directory

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, web-config, virtual-directory

I'm receiving the 500.19 error in IIS7 for a virtual directory that I've added for an applicaiton. The HResult code is 0x80070003. The error message is "The requested page cannot be accessed because the related configuration data for the page is invalid."

I've checked the MSDN article at http://support.microsoft.com/kb/942055, but none of these issues point to the HResult that I'm receiving. In fact, in this virtual directory, there are no configuration files. The only files located there are shared images and PDF files.

Thanks in advance for any assistance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nevermind. I figured it out before a post. The virtual directory is configured to point to a mapped network drive. That cannot work as it only exists during the current logged in session. I needed to use a fully qualified domain path.